# client.getInputStream returns null

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the WifiDirect demo api to send a recorded audio to another android device but input stream from the socket always returns null.
Any help is much appreciated.

Here are portion of the code

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
            final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), File.separator + "SuDAB/received/"
                    + "sudab-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".3gp");

            File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
            if (!dirs.exists()) {
                dirs.mkdirs();
            }
            f.createNewFile();

            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream(); 

            copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
            serverSocket.close();
            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (inputStream == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        Log.v(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Time taken to transfer all bytes is : " + endTime);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is how i pass the file to be sent to the FileTransferService

```
mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps
                    TextView statusText = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
                    statusText.setText("Sending: " + lastFile);
                    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Intent----------- " + lastFile);
                    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileTransferService.class);
                    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "File transfer service created...");
                    serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, lastFile);
                    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
                            info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
                    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
                    getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: 'this is how i pass the file to be sent to the FileTransferService'. No. With that you only pass a file name. Not interesting. You could better post the code with which you send the contents of the file.

Comment: @greenapps could you please clarify a little bit more,  because i'm not sure I understand. I'm passing the file name alright. That's because putExtra is taking string parameter over there. Please also let me know what you mean by sending the contents of the file. Thank you.

Comment: I later released what i was doing wrong after noticing deep in debugging that there was a FileNotFoundException being thrown. lastFile should have been started with file://. Thanks @greenapps

Comment: You do not have to thank me as it comes out that a file name was enough. Only you missed the 'file://' protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, lastFile);
```

should be

```
serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, "file://"+lastFile);
```

instead.